# "my best pair of pyjamas' / "my best pyjamas"

Tags: plural-forms

> I can’t find **my best pair of pyjamas**/pajamas.
>
> I can’t find **my best pyjamas**/pajamas.

Am I right despite the fact that more correctly to use the first version, the second version is more common in that context? Is it right only if we speak about the clothes/things that had been bought before? I guess, if we go to the shop, we need to buy 2 pairs of pyjamas (not 2 pyjamas).

Comment: In that context, both sentences are fine, and equally correct. It's the same as, "my favourite shoes/pair of shoes" or "socks" or anything that comes in pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply comes down to the difference between 'pyjamas' and 'a pair of pyjamas'. Nothing else about your example sentence affects it.

'Pyjamas' is a plural term, as most pyjamas do come as a pair of garments, usually a top and bottoms. However, the plural term is often used in British English as a general, uncountable term covering all kinds of sleepwear, which might include single garments as well as those that come in pairs. For example, one might say "I'm putting on my pyjamas" to mean nightwear in general. So, 'pyjamas' and 'a pair of pyjamas' could, in some uses, be completely interchangeable. However, if counting pairs, we would state that they were pairs (ie "two *pairs* of pyjamas"), or else call the garment by its proper name.

Note that some kinds of sleepwear do have their own terms, for example 'onesies' which some people wear as pyjamas. A single item of this kind is 'a onesie', yet some may casually term them 'pyjamas'.

Comment: The question is about classical pyjamas (top and bottom). The question is exactly about examples when 'one's pyjamas' and 'a pair of pyjamas' are interchangeable and noninterchangeable (if it can be). The answer don't give information about that.

Comment: @Sergei I believe I have answered that. Two-piece pyjamas may be called both 'pyjamas' **and** 'a pair of pyjamas'. But I have to explain the difference between single-piece pyjamas, because if I simply said they were always interchangeable that would be misleading for you and for future readers.